# How can I crop a JPG image to fit a CSS layout using border-radius in percentages?

Tags: css, image, jpeg, image-resizing, border-radius

So,while making up the layout i faced some problems connected with image insertion in web document
Could not find exact ratio of perecentages to crop up the image perefectly as in layout.

I tried this line of code:

```css
border-radius: 90% 0 52% 52% / 60% 0 31% 31%;
```

Though there is still white circled line over there

[This is the image of how it is in layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ME6xK.png)
[And this is JPG image file that should be cropped up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNMDW.jpg)

Comment: Please see [ask] and make a [mre] here so that we can reproduce the problem ourselves.

Answer (score -1):

You need a

```
clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
```

take a look at this

The clip-path CSS property creates a clipping region that sets what part of an element should be shown. Parts that are inside the region are shown, while those outside are hidden.

polygon()
Defines a polygon using an SVG filling rule and a set of vertices.

for example:
you can shape the poligon into a triangle:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.image-container {
  width: 40%;
  height: 20em;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

.cropped-image {
/*   height: 100%; */
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
}
```

```html
<main class="container">
      <figure class="image-container">
        <h1>Before Cropping</h1>
        <img
          src="https://i.imgur.com/jijeTMT.jpeg"
          alt="Photo by XPS on Unsplash"
          class=""
          width="1920"
          height="1282"
          loading="lazy"
        />
      </figure>
      
      <article class="image-container">
        <h1>After Cropping</h1>
        <img
          src="https://i.imgur.com/jijeTMT.jpeg"
          alt="Photo by XPS on Unsplash"
          class="cropped-image"
          width="1920"
          height="1282"
          loading="lazy"
        />
      </article>
    </main>
```

Comment: How does this path that creates a triangle shape help? A code-only (and almost link-only) answer is not helpful.

Comment: Shape the polygon as you need to, that is not fixed in a triangle. the triangle is just an example what you can do with polygon. did you expect us to do the work for you or you need a solution to your problem?

Comment: It's not *my* problem *per se*, but an answer with only a *property* and a link is not a helpful answer: What does this property do? How may one use it in their work should they need to create the shame shape as what OP needs? If you are telling readers to research themselves (by visiting the link, the docs, etc.), then let this be a comment, not an answer, since it doesn't really provide anything on its own without those links.

Comment: @inSync better?